# Why does my Nodemailer POST request work in postman but not from my react front-end?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, nodemailer

I am using the Nodemailer package and a SendinBlue smtp email server to create a website contact form. When I send a request using postman the email sends and everything works as it should, however, when I try an Axios post request from my react front-end (in both production and live environments) I get the following:

POST http:///send 404 (Not Found)

My Server.js file:

```html
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
}

// Catch all route to redirect unmanaged routes back to the react app.
// THIS OPTION IS NOT SEO OPTIMIZED
// THIS ROUTE SENDS ALL SAVED LINKS TO THE ROOT
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/')
});

// CONNECTION NOT YET TESTED

// Nodemailer config to handle contact form submit.
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-relay.sendinblue.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
  },
});

// Post route for contact form submission
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  var { name, email, message } = req.body;
  let mailOptions = {
    from: `"${name}" <${email}>`, //'"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', sender address
    to: `${process.env.EMAIL}`, // list of receivers
    subject: "Atlas Pet Contact Form",
    text: `${message}`, // plain text body
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Email Sent')
    }
  });
  res.json('Email Sent');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`) })
```

React contact component:

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../../pages/style.css";

function ContactForm() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        message: ""
    });

    function sendEmail(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post("/send", formData)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    };

    function handleNameChange(e) {
        setFormData({ ...formData, name: e.target.value })
    };

    function handleEmailChange(e) {
        setFormData({ ...formData, email: e.target.value })
    };

    function handleMessageChange(e) {
        setFormData({ ...formData, message: e.target.value })
    };

    return (
        <div className="jumbotron form-spacing">
            <form className="form">
                <h1 className="display-4 main-txt"><strong>Drop a Line</strong></h1>
                <br/>
                <div className="hr"></div>
                <br/>
                <p className="lead main-txt">Questions, Comments, Concerns? Let us know!</p>
                {/* Name input */}
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                    className="inputs"
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    onChange={handleNameChange}
                ></input>
                <br />
                {/* Email input */}
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input
                    className="inputs"
                    type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleEmailChange}
                ></input>
                <br />
                {/* Message input */}
                <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                <textarea
                    className="inputs"
                    rows="6"
                    id="message"
                    name="message"
                    onChange={handleMessageChange}
                ></textarea>
                {/* Submit button */}
                <button
                    className="submit-btn btn btn-light btn-submit"
                    type="submit"
                    value="Send Message"
                    onClick={sendEmail}
                >Send Message</button>
            </form>
            <div className="row-overlay"></div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: I think you're url in axios is incomplete can you tell us what url did you pass in postman ? should be something like ```http://localhost:3001/send```?

Comment: @antoineso that's exactly right! My postman url is `http://localhost:3001/send`. Do I need more than just the /send when using axios?

Comment: yes axios need the complete url because we use axios mostly to consume external api so you need to pass the entire url.

Comment: @antoineso when I use the full URL I'm still getting a POST https://URL/send 404 (Not Found) in production and locally I'm being blocked by a CORS policy. Any ideas? It does work this way in Postman still.